# Chrome Extension : Toggle content_script via browser_action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I toggle script/content in page using browser action button?

Example:

- click browser_action button
- add div to current tab
- click browser_action button
- remove div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, just found an answer.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi

```
/* in background.html */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
});

/* in manifest.json */
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
```